# confused about a pair of recursion relations

Tags: recurrence

thanks in advance for your help in figuring this out. I'm taking an algorithms class and I'm stuck on something. According to the professor, the following holds true where C(1)=1 and n is a power of 2:

`C(n) = 2 * C(n/2) + n` resolves to `C(n) = n * lg(n) + n`

`C(n) = 2 * C(n/2) + lg(n)` resolves to `C(n) = 3 * n - lg(n) - 2`

The first one I completely grok. As I understand the form, what's stated is that C(n) resolves to two sub-problems, each of which requires n/2 work to solve, and an additional n amount of work to split and merge everything. As such, for every division of the problem, the constant 2 is increased by a factor of ^k (where k is the number of splits), the 2 in n/2 is also increased by a factor of ^k for much the same reason, and the last n is multiplied by a factor of k because each split creates a multiple of k extra work.

My confusion stems from the second relation. Given that the first and second relations are almost identical, why isn't the result of the second something like nlgn+(lgn^2)?

Comment: More relevant for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general result is the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

But in this specific case, you can work out the math for a power of 2:

```
C(2^k) 
= 2 * C(2^(k-1)) + lg(2^k) 
= 4 * C(2^(k-2)) + lg(2^k) + 2 * lg(2^(k-1))
= ... repeat ...
= 2^k * C(1) + sum (from i=1 to k) 2^(k-i) * lg 2^i
= 2^k + lg(2) * sum (from i=1 to k) 2^(i) * i
= 2^k - 2 + 2^k+1 - k
= 3 * 2^k - k - 2 
= 3 * n - lg(n) - 2
```

Comment: first - thank you so much for your response. I very much appreciate it!

pressing onward - I'm still confused. I tried applying the master method and I must've screwed up somewhere. I ended up with    

i=1/n=4: c(n) = 2^2 * C(n/2^2) + 3lg(n) - 2    

i=2/n=8: c(n) = 2^3 * C(n/n^3) + 5lg(n) - 2^4    

...    

C(n) = 2^k * C(n/2^k) + [(k+i) * lg(n)] - 2^k+1    

If I'm on the right track here, I have no idea how to get from here to 3 * n - lg(n) - 2.

Comment: ps - sorry about the formatting. I couldn't get the line breaks to work correctly :-/

Comment: Are you asking how to extend the result to an arbitrary number (not just a power of 2) or how to show that `sum (from i=1 to k) 2^(i) * i = - 2 + 2^k+1 - k` ?

Comment: I'm asking two questions: 1) am I correct in assuming that my attempt to solve the recursion is flawed? 2) yes, I'm confused as to how sum (from i=1 to k) 2^(i) * i = - 2 + 2^k+1 - k, as well as the rest of it. My suspicion is that there's some critical step that I'm missing that's screwing up my numbers and I don't know what it is.

Comment: what about this: when I work the recurrence slightly differently, I end up with  
  
C(n) = 2^3C(n/2^3) + 2^2lg(n/2^2) + 2^2lg(n/2) + 2^2lg(n)  ----  

is my analysis of the recurrence gtg up and to this point at least?